# SQL. How select rows which have all needed conditions

Tags: sql, mariadb

This is my table:

[image: This is my table]

How do I modify my query

```
SELECT sif_id, sif_item_id, sif_svid FROM shop_items_filters
WHERE sif_svid IN (2,9,26) group by sif_item_id
```

How can I modify my query to get only those rows that have all the required `sif_svid`, grouped by `item_id`?

For example, sif_svid IN (2,9,26) only has item_id=2.

Comment: Do **not** post images of tables. Post the `CREATE` and `INSERT` statements as **text**.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `HAVING` clause which asserts your logic:

```sql
SELECT sif_item_id
FROM shop_items_filters
WHERE sif_svid IN (2, 9, 26)
GROUP BY sif_item_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT sif_svid) = 3;
```

If you need all columns, then use:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM shop_items_filters
WHERE sif_item_id IN (
    SELECT sif_item_id
    FROM shop_items_filters
    WHERE sif_svid IN (2, 9, 26)
    GROUP BY sif_item_id
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT sif_svid) = 3
);
```